# Why pyinstaller throws error on method while script execute without error?

Tags: python, tkinter, syntax-error, pyinstaller, args

Scripts run without problem, but when I try to make an .exe it throws following error:

```
Syntax error in d:\Archive\Work\Python\Project v2\tkintertest1.py
  File "d:\Archive\Work\Python\Project v2\tkintertest1.py", line 810
     def changeplan(*args, widget=None):
                            ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried changing part of code from script, but I'm beginner and haven't found proper replacement.

```
def changeplan(*args, widget=None):
    widget.get()
    for i in self.treeplan.get_children():
        self.treeplan.delete(i)
    self.db_refreshplan(pforder, pfdate, pfmarker, pfstyle, pfsize, pffabric, pftype, pfcolor, pfcomment, pfdiff)
    planfilters()
```

In the end I just want to make executable from script!

Comment: this line doesn't work in Python 2 so it seems pyinstaller uses Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Comment: problem is `*` in Python 2 so if you don't use `args` in function then remove `*args` from definition.

Comment: @furas Thank you. I forgot to mention that I use Python 3.7.

Comment: you may try to install with `pip3 install pyinstaller` or `python3 -m pip install pyinstaller` and maybe it will work with Python 3

Comment: Thnx @furas. I did checked and it was running with 2.7